# BVP eigenvalue and e.function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, boundary-value-problem

> Consider the boundary-value problem introduced in the construction of the mathematical model for the shape of a rotating string:
>
> $$Ty'' + \rho\omega^2y = 0, \quad y(0) = 0, \quad y(L) = 0$$
>
> For constants $T$ and $\rho$, define the critical speeds of angular rotation ωn as the values of $\omega$ for which the boundary-value problem has nontrivial solutions. Find the critical speeds $\omega_n$ and the corresponding deflections $y_n(x)$.
>
> (Give your answers in terms of $n$, making sure that each value of $n$ corresponds to a unique critical speed.)

I set $\rho\omega^2/T = a$, simplifying everything

$a < 0$ and $a = 0$ turn trivial

For $a > 0$ I end up with:

$$c_2\sin(aL) = 0 $$ thus $$ aL = \pi, 2\pi, 3\pi \dots =n\pi $$

$$ a = \frac{n\pi}{L} $$

$$\frac{\rho\omega^2}{T} = \frac{n\pi}{L} $$ leaving me with:

$$\omega_n = \sqrt{\frac{n\pi T}{\rho L}} $$ which unfortunately is wrong..

Where did I go wrong? Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

If $$ a = \frac{\rho\omega^2}{T} $$

You should have

$$ y'' + ay = 0 $$

Then
$$ y(x) = \sin (\sqrt{a} x) $$

where

$$ \sqrt{a}L = n\pi $$

so
$$ a_n = \left(\frac{n\pi}{L}\right)^2 = \frac{\rho\omega^2}{T} $$
$$ \omega_n = \frac{n\pi}{L}\sqrt{\frac{T}{\rho}}$$